# WCF service for gSOAP client

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap, gsoap

I have received a request to build a Service to handle trafic from a predesigned client.

The documentation stated the service is a SOAP service but I later found out the protocol used by the predesigned client is gSOAP using SOAP 1.2

The issue I get is that when assigning the Binding to `basicHttpBinding` the error I get i `Action '' not supported`, since the client does not send the `SOAPAction` header (as it is not used in SOAP 1.2) and if I set the binding of my WCF service with `wsHttpBinfing` I get the error

```
HTTP/1.1 415 
Cannot process the message because the content type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' 
was not the expected type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.
```

So basicly it seems he gSOAP client they use sends the SOAP structure of SOAP 1.2 but with the Content-Type of SOAP 1.1

My question in this is how do I get my WCF service to handle the requests from the client.
(The client cannot be modified in any way)

I have tried setting up a customBinding

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="myCustomBinding">
      <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
      <httpTransport/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

with various messageVersion values. But I have yet to find a combination that works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved by creating a custom Dispatcher to map calls based on the SOAPBody.

Solution found in a Microsoft WCF Samples.

Samples found at:

[Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) and Windows Workflow Foundation (WF) Samples for .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=21459)

Exact example (based on the folder the samples are installed in is)

> Extensibility\Interop\AdvancedDispatchByBody

Comment: Please edit your answer and include the link to the sample that helped.  :)